# Slow local network (device in the same room) speed when connected to vpn

Tags: windows-10, networking, openvpn, network-shares, network-drive

I have a mapped drive on my local network. When I copy files from or to it without a VPN connection, I have a speed 4-5 times greater than when I'm connected to VPN.

Obviously, something is wrong, because VPN shouldn't affect local traffic at all.

My stack: latest windows 10, OpenVPN client 2.4.7, network drive on windows 2019 datacenter.

Again, after disconnecting from the VPN speed immediately raise up back to normal. I also suppressing local DNS in VPN settings (block-outside-dns) in my configuration. Can it somehow affect speed to local network drives?

What can be a problem here? It's hard to google something similar, most people have a problem with accessing network drives through VPN instead.

Comment: How about open the folder in mapped drive directly? Will it still be slow?

Comment: @Candy Yes, opening folders or files on mapped drives visually becomes slow too.